# Regex Help: One charecter, followed by at least one digit

Tags: regex

I require a regex that will text that a string starts with one chaecter (a-z) and is followed by at least one digit.

I have tried...

> `^[a-zA-Z]{1}\d+`

my test data is...

```
a1234 (pass)
B123444434 (pass)
Z098745 (pass)
ZZ12345 (fail)
G4b553b3 (fail)
```

The problem is that the last two lines shoudl fail but dont, Im not sure if the problem is my regex or my c# (below);

```
    int pass = 0;
    int fail = 0;

    string[] testdata = 
    {
        "a1234", 
        "B1234", 
        "Z098745", 
        "ZZ12345", 
        "G4b5533", 
    };

    string sPattern = "[a-zA-Z]{1}\\d+";

    foreach (string s in testdata)
    {
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern))
        {
            pass++;
        }
        else
        {
            fail++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `{1}` doesn't actually do anything. `[a-zA-Z]` will only match one character unless followed by a quantifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have missed `^` in your code, so `Z12345` matches for `ZZ12345` and `b5533` matches for `G4b5533`.

And as it was mentioned, `{1}` is redundant.

I believe you should have

```
string sPattern = "^[a-zA-Z]\\d+$";
```

in your code.

Answer (score -1):

After a rethink (and a good nights sleep), I have come up with this...

```
^[A-Za-z]{1}\d+.$*[0-9]$
```

•   Must start with a character a-z (not case sensitive)

•   First character must be followed by at least one numerical digit

•   Last character must be a numerical digit (to prevent "A1234A" or "A1A" matching)

Thanks for all the help Vladimir and jornak.

Comment: Tim - do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @Vladimir's regex is perfect, according to your problem specification. What do you not like about it?